# Can anybody tell me what is on this picture? I think is hebrew

Tags: hebrew

[image]

I saw this on a car in my city yesterday, and I have seen several cars with it. Not sure if it's a new trending, if it means something, if it meaningful. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an image of the hebrew alphabet, and I believe the characters are:

Aleph Lamed Dalet

Seems to be one of the 72 names given to God in the Kabbalah.

[image]

After using Google, I believe I found the answer:

[image]

ALEPH LAMED DALED: Protection from evil eye & bad dreams. Helps rebirthing process.